# itk image from numpy not a supported type for interpolator

Tags: python, numpy, itk

I've created an itk image from a numpy array (float32) of size (r, c, 3)

```
itk_img = itk.image_view_from_array(arr, is_vector=True)
```

But I can't instanciate an interpolator  with the image type:

```
image_type = type(itk_img)  # itk.itkVectorImagePython.itkVectorImageF2
interpolator = itk.LinearInterpolateImageFunction[image_type, itk.D].New()
```

```
Supported input types:
itk.Image[itk.SS,2]
itk.Image[itk.UC,2]
itk.Image[itk.US,2]
itk.Image[itk.F,2]
itk.Image[itk.D,2]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,2],2]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,2],2]
itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],2]
itk.Image[itk.RGBAPixel[itk.UC],2]
itk.Image[itk.SS,3]
itk.Image[itk.UC,3]
itk.Image[itk.US,3]
itk.Image[itk.F,3]
itk.Image[itk.D,3]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,3],3]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,3],3]
itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],3]
itk.Image[itk.RGBAPixel[itk.UC],3]
itk.Image[itk.SS,4]
itk.Image[itk.UC,4]
itk.Image[itk.US,4]
itk.Image[itk.F,4]
itk.Image[itk.D,4]
itk.Image[itk.Vector[itk.F,4],4]
itk.Image[itk.CovariantVector[itk.F,4],4]
itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],4]
itk.Image[itk.RGBAPixel[itk.UC],4]
```

Creating the resampler with image_type works fine.

I just can't find a working combination of types...
Is 3 float vector  not supported in python ?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If your pixel type were UC instead of F, your image would be `itk.Image[itk.RGBPixel[itk.UC],2]` (based on [the relevant code](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITK/blob/a8ca2578c53906cf2116413c74c27f2aa037e464/Wrapping/Generators/Python/itk/support/extras.py#L382-L388)), which is a supported pixel type. So either cast to UC (`itk_img = itk_img.astype(itk.UC)`) or use [RescaleIntensity](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1RescaleIntensityImageFilter.html).

Comment: Thanks ! I would like to keep the type as it is. It is intrinsically float data, and I would loose some precision by converting to UC...

Answer (score 0):

Compile ITK from source, and enable the extra type wrapping to suit your needs.

Way 1: build ITK with ITK_WRAP_PYTHON=ON and other relevant options, then copy the `WrapITK.pth` build tree file to your virtual environment or conda environment site-packages, see [release docs](https://discourse.itk.org/t/itk-5-2-0-has-been-released/4165#python-package-layout-improvements-5).

Way 2: follow the instructions for [creating a custom wheel](https://itkpythonpackage.readthedocs.io/en/master/Build_ITK_Python_packages.html).